# Not redirecting to Salesforce login page while opening the app

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, cordova, salesforce-sdk-android, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

forcedroid version 4.0.0
cordova version 5.4.1
phonegap version 5.3.9
cordova platform version android 5.0.0
mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

I followed the below steps to create a new app,

```
$ forcedroid create
   hybrid_local
   myApp
   /Users/itsme/projects/
   com.demo.myapp

Creating a new cordova project.
/Users/itsme/projects/myApp /Users/itsme/projects
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.demo.myapp
    Name: myApp
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-23
Android project created with cordova-android@5.0.0
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Fetching plugin "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin" via git clone
Repository "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin" checked out to git ref "master".
Installing "com.salesforce" for android
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" via npm
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
Running SalesforceMobileSDK plugin android post-install script
The node package shelljs is required to use this script. Run 'npm install shelljs' before running this script.
/Users/itsme/projects/myApp

Your application project is ready in /Users/itsme/projects/
```

Then, I ran the following code

```
$ cd myApp
$ cordova build
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ cordova emulate android
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   INSTALL SUCCESS
   LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

I see an empty screen in my emulator with below error in the browser console i.e., via chrome://inspect/#devices

```
No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.
```

[image]

I added the following line in my `index.html`,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *; frame-src *;">
```

Checked the `config.html`,

```
<allow-navigation href="https://localhost" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.force.com" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.salesforce.com" />
<access origin="https://localhost" />
<access origin="https://*.force.com" />
<access origin="https://*.salesforce.com" />
```

When I re-built it, there was no error or warnings but I still see the empty page. I am not sure why this simple app is not redirecting to the Salesforce login page, am i missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Same steps worked well for me and I see the login screen when I launch the app. I see the following error in your log

```
The node package shelljs is required to use this script. Run 'npm install shelljs' before running this script.
/Users/itsme/projects/myApp
```

Update - I see this issue was logged on the Mobile SDK repo and has been closed as an environmental issue related to your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is the discussion going on, https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1019